# Electric field of finite sheet: Full analytical solution of integration?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, physics

I am trying to work out the integral
$$
\operatorname{E}_{z}\left(x,y,z\right) =
\alpha\int\int\frac{z\,\mathrm{d}x'\,\mathrm{d}y'}
{\left[\left(x - x'\right)^{2} + \left(y -y'\right)^{2} + z^{2}\right]^{3/2}}
$$ with the limits $$-\frac{a}{2}\leq dx'\leq\frac{a}{2}\qquad-\frac{b}{2}\leq dy'\leq\frac{b}{2}$$ Mathematica does not return the solution in a reasonable time and I can't seem to find it.

This integral is for the $z$ component of the electric field of a homogeneously charged finite sheets in the $z=0$ plane. The sheets dimensions are $a \cdot b$. The integrals that need to be solved are detailed on the second page of [this text](http://plaza.obu.edu/corneliusk/mp/ers.pdf). Note that The three integrals are for $E_x$, $E_y$ and $E_z$ (typo in the linked document).

I solved the $E_x$ and $E_y$ integrals in Mathematica and I would be grateful for some help or a pointer to get the analytical expression for $E_z$.

Comment: Perhaps taking one of the integrals first then the other might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This integral may be done analytically as far as I can see.  First, for the inner integral over $y'$, use a trig substitution $y'=y+\sqrt{(z^2+(x-x')^2} \tan{\theta}$ to transform the integral into

$$\alpha z \int_{-a/2}^{a/2} \frac{dx'}{z^2+(x-x')^2} \, \int_{-\arctan{((b/2)+y)/\sqrt{(z^2+(x-x')^2}}}^{\arctan{((b/2)-y)/\sqrt{(z^2+(x-x')^2}}} d\theta \frac{\cos{\theta}}{\sin^3{\theta}}$$

The inner integral has a simple antiderivative, and after some algebra, we are down to single integrals:

$$\frac{\alpha z}{2} \left (\frac{b}{2}+y\right)^2 \int_{-a/2}^{a/2} \frac{dx'}{\left[ (x-x')^2+\left (\frac{b}{2}+y\right)^2+z^2\right ]\left[(x-x')^2+z^2 \right ]} - \\\frac{\alpha z}{2} \left (\frac{b}{2}-y\right)^2 \int_{-a/2}^{a/2} \frac{dx'}{\left[ (x-x')^2+\left (\frac{b}{2}-y\right)^2+z^2\right ]\left[(x-x')^2+z^2 \right ]}$$

Using partial fraction decompositions, we may simplify the above expression drastically to get

$$\frac{\alpha z}{2} \int_{-a/2}^{a/2} dx' \left [\frac{1}{(x-x')^2+\left (\frac{b}{2}-y\right)^2+z^2}- \frac{1}{(x-x')^2+\left (\frac{b}{2}+y\right)^2+z^2} \right ]$$

These integrals are expressible in terms of arctan, and I assume you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you very much Ron! That is a beautiful approach which makes the final integral much easier than I had thought. It is not a problem for Mathematica and indeed gives a nicer expression than the software finds. Another interesting lesson I learned today is about Mathematica: When giving it definite integrals, it worries a lot about the boundaries and their nature (are they complex, etc.) so that it takes much longer to solve than an indefinite integral. All of the three integrals in the above PDF are solved by Mathematica in seconds if you provide them as indefinite integrals.